# What is the best way to await for a function?

Tags: node.js, function, async-await

I have this function:

```js
function verifyToken(name, token) {
    const sql = "SELECT secret FROM twofactor where name = ?"
    const params = [name]
    
    db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
        if (err) return null;
        
        const verify = twoFactor.verifyToken(row.secret, token);
        return verify != null && verify.delta == "0";
    });
}
```

It get's a value from a SQLite DB, uses that value in another function.

I want to use this function in an if statement, like this:

```js
var errors = []

//More checks here

if (!verifyToken(req.body.username, req.body.token)) {
    errors.push("Invalid token");
}

if (errors.length) {
    res.status(400).json({
        "error": errors.join(", ")
    });
    return;
}

//Proceed with other code, everything is valid :)
```

But currently it won't wait for the function to return it's value. What is the best way to wait for the function to return a value, and if false, add text to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sqlite lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite#getting-a-single-row) supports `async` / `await`, you don't need to use callbacks

```
async function verifyToken(name, token) {
  const sql = "SELECT secret FROM twofactor where name = ?"
  const row = await db.get(sql, [name]);
  const verify = twoFactor.verifyToken(row.secret, token);
  return verify && verify.delta == '0';
}
```

Benefit there is, naturally, your `verifyToken` function is now awaitable (just make the calling function `async`) e.g.

```
app.post("/url", async (req, res) => {
  var errors = []
  //More checks here

  const { username, token } = req.body;
  const verified = await verifyToken(username, token);
  if (!verified) {
    errors.push("Invalid token");
  }

  if (errors.length) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errors.join(", ")
    });
  }

  //Proceed
})
```

Comment: I was using the sqlite3 lib, that's why it wasn't working. Moving to sqlite fixed to problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Either you could use Promises or async await so as to wait for the token verification and accordingly proceed for next operation!

```js
const verifyToken = (name, token) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = "SELECT secret FROM twofactor where name = ?";
        const params = [name]

        db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            const verify = twoFactor.verifyToken(row.secret, token);
            if (verify != null && verify.delta == "0") {
                resolve(verify);
            }
        });
    });

}

var errors = []

//More checks here

verifyToken(req.body.username, req.body.token).then((verify) => {
    if (!verify) {
        errors.push("Invalid token");
    }
 if (errors.length) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errors.join(", ")
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with Promise to return async function.
Use await on your function to wait for the response.

```js
async function verifyToken(name, token, callback) {
    const sql = "SELECT secret FROM twofactor where name = ?"
    const params = [name]
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
         db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
            if (err) return rej(null);

            const verify = twoFactor.verifyToken(row.secret, token);
            res(verify != null && verify.delta == "0");
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: The function doesn't need to be `async`, just return the `Promise`. Also, why would you not return the error from the DB call?

Comment: @James your asking me? that what he did.
The function should be async to let the user know that it return promise for async result.

Comment: the difference is in the OPs code they aren't actually returning anything, in your case you are (via the Promise). That's not the purpose of `async`, unless intend on using `await` then it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's better convert a callback function into a Promise inside a function, then run it asynchronously. Play with `reject` and `resolve` in your Promise according to whether the query result is good or not.

```
function verifyToken(name, token, callback) {
    const sql = "SELECT secret FROM twofactor where name = ?"
    const params = [name]

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
          if (err)
            reject(null)
          else {
            const verify = twoFactor.verifyToken(row.secret, token);
            if (!verify || verify.delta === "0")
               reject(verify)
            else
               resolve(verify);
          }
      });
    })
}
```

Calling:

```
(async () => {
  await verifyToken(req.body.username, req.body.token)
    .then(result => {
      //  do whatever with your successful result
    })
    .catch(err => {
      //  oops, this was unsuccessful...
    })
});
```

Comment: Using `await` and `then` together is a bit confusing.

Comment: Why is that? I'm doing this very often. Particularly if I have to chain a lot of asynchronous events.

Comment: Because its counter intuitive, `async` / `await` is syntactic sugar so you don't have to use chaining. For example, when you `await verifyToken(...)`, the return value will be what you get in `then`.

Comment: I meant chaining a lot of thens after an async function. Typically when I have to open a zip file, extract files, then process each of them in some way, then upload them to S3, etc.

Comment: but why chain? Just `await` the next call ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Because the first call must end before the next one begins - obviously - and I also need to know if it failed or not.